# Diffent number of rows from different columns into one table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a populated table *book* (accountability) with, among others, four columns of interest:

```
text, amount, debit (account_number) , credit (account_number)
```

I want a list of the number of occurences ***oc*** of each different value **fi** from each column (debit, credit, amount). I filter rows out using the text-column and set the number of occurences to be more than 1 (**having oc > 1**):  (example with 'debit'). This is my query:

```
SELECT 'debit' , fi , COUNT(fi) oc FROM
    (
    SELECT debit fi, text 
    FROM book
    WHERE text
    LIKE '%Supermarket SMILE%'
) t1
GROUP BY fi
HAVING oc > 1
```

Here comes an example of this output (and the two other columns when I replace debit with credit or amount in the query):

```
+-------+------+----+    +--------+------+----+    +--------+--------+----+
| debit | fi   | oc |    | credit | fi   | oc |    | amount |  fi    | oc |
+-------+------+----+    +--------+------+----+    +--------+--------+----+
| debit |   70 |  2 |    | credit |   89 |  8 |    | amount | 136.95 |  2 |
| debit |  111 | 11 |    +--------+------+----+    | amount | 200.34 |  3 |
+-------+------+----+                              | amount | 136.95 |  2 |
                                                   +--------+--------+----+
```

Is it possible to combine all this into one output using a query in MySQL? (I don't need the occurences anymore):

```
+-------+--------+--------+
| debit | credit | amount |
+-------+--------+--------+
|    70 |   89   | 136.95 |
|   111 |        | 200.34 |
|       |        | 136.95 |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a temp table and select from your 3 tables into that one table.

```
INSERT INTO #tempTable
SELECT debit,t2.column1,t3.column1 etc ... and join on the other 2 tables and select
from those tables the columns you need as well.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought of a more straight way: without inserts, tables etc. but I'll give a try.

Comment: I've tried it. It works, thank you. Though, I finally chose to use UNION to put the three tables together and then treat the result of my query in my php script.